# Blank page after updating to v2 ngrx/store

Tags: typescript, angular, ngrx

After updating to **ngrx/store** from v1 to v2 (no middleware), my app shows a blank page. And my **ngrx/router** also stops redirecting the page (in v1, if I go to a non-existing page, it will redirect to an existing page).

There is no warning and error.

This is my console, when I am using v1:

[image]

This is v2:

[image]

This is my part of codes if it helps:

```
bootstrap(App, [
  Title,
  Location,

  // ... my service

  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' }),

  provideStore(
    compose(
      storeLogger(),
      combineReducers
    )({
      // ... my reducer

      router: routerReducer
    })
  ),
  provideRouter(appRouter),
  connectRouterToStore(),
]);
```

Parent router:

```
export const appRouter: Routes = [
  { path: '/',
    component: LandingComponent,
    index: { component: StartComponent },
    loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(landingRouter))
  },

  { path: '/admin',
    guards: [AdminGuard],
    component: AdminComponent,
    index: { component: DashboardComponent },
    loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(adminRouter))
  },

  { path: '/home', guards: [LoginGuard], component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/settings', guards: [LoginGuard], component: SettingsComponent },
  // ... my other components, similar

  { path: '/**', redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

What may cause the blank page and not redirecting? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @DzmitryShylovich for pointing out the issue on Gitter!

It is because **ngrx/router-store** does not work well with v2 **ngrx/store**.

So only needs to remove `connectRouterToStore()`, then it works well again.

You can track this issue [here](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store/issues/4) on GitHub.